# Accessing the Internet Via a Hardware Device plugged to a Socket

Tags: hardware-acceleration, hardware

I am a software developer and I am not really deep into hardwares. Please I will need clarification and answers to this.

I am looking at working with a plug-like structure/device that when it is plugged to the socket (the normal home socket for your chargers and the rest), If there is electricity, it automatically loads a web address (already programmed) with some parameters (obviously, we won't be able to see it). The website will be able to detected it (That's the software engineering part which is not important now)

The point is When the device is plugged to a socket, it loads an already programmed web address.

I tried checking online for resources that can be helpful but most are referencing USB which is not exactly what I want.

USB must be plugged to a device but this Plug or device will be plugged to a Socket (just to get electricity).

PS: I know the device will need to have an OS and internet connection.

Kindly assist, if you have relating answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a simple ping, a wifi-enabled microcontroller like the [ESP32](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13907) may work for your application. There are many example libraries for this type of behavior - [SimplePing](https://github.com/marian-craciunescu/ESP32Ping/blob/master/examples/SimplePing/SimplePing.ino) is one example that may be helpful.

These boards are not necessarily tied to an outlet though for power - they can be battery powered (such as the example I linked above). If this is a restriction for you, you may need to look at a different hardware platform.